# sound is not coming out from speakers

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio

Why isn't any sound coming from my pc speakers after i installed windows 7 ultimate from windows xp. I have check everything and did troubleshooting in the hardware and sound option in the control panel. The audio icon says no audio device connected, please help.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do when installing an operating system is to install any drivers the hardware requires to operate.

Click on the start menu and type [into the search bar] `Device Manager` and go into the found item. Is there anything listed with a yellow warning/exclamation mark? For those items you will need to install drivers for the operating system to be able to use that device. One of these flagged will be your sound card, which will explain why you have no sound.

If this is your issue you can try this;

- right click on that item (in device manager)
- select the `Driver` tab
- hit `Update Driver...`
- select `Search automatically for updated driver software`
- follow [this tutorial](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows7/automatically-get-recommended-drivers-and-updates-for-your-hardware) and try again if the next screen does not say `Searching online for software`

If it installed it then great! You may need to restart but sound should return to your machine. If, however, it responds with something like `The best driver for your device is already installed` or `No driver found` then you need to download it yourself.

Follow [this tutorial](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-find-unknown-device-drivers-by-their-vendor-device-id/) to try to find out what the device is (if you dont know its name, i.e. it shows up as `Unknown device`), then simply google that device's manufacturer to find their support page and locate your device. They should provide a driver download link for Windows 7. Good luck.